# Как кодировать/декодировать изображения Google WebP в Delphi, используя libwebp.dll?

Tags: delphi, webp

Работаю с библиотекой libwebp.dll, которая позволяет декодировать/кодировать изображения из (в) формата Google WebP.

На сайте [Code.google.com](https://code.google.com/archive/p/delphi-webp/source/default/source) в репозитории, который находится [тут](https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-source/v2/code.google.com/delphi-webp/source-archive.zip) (Dll + pas модуль - 182 КБ) была найдена библиотека **libwebp.dll**, которая вроде бы как позволяет производить манипуляции с вышеуказанным форматом.
К библиотеке прилагается обертка **libwebp.pas**, в которой находятся необходимые мне функции:

```
    // Декодирование изображения 
function WebPDecodeRGB(const data: PByte; data_size: Cardinal; width, height: PInteger): PByte; cdecl; external LIB_WEBP;


//Кодирование изображения
function WebPEncodeRGB(const rgb: PByte; width, height, stride: Integer;   quality_factor: single; var output: PByte): Cardinal; cdecl; external LIB_WEBP;
```

Но как их правильно вызвать я не понимаю, точнее не понимаю как правильно вызывать параметры, которые должны быть в этих функциях. В конечном итоге хочется просто видеть два примера работы с данной библиотекой. А точнее как изображение из формата Google WebP декодировать в обычное битовое изображение в формате BMP, и соответственно обратная операция.

Почитав [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548725/how-do-i-display-a-webp-image-in-a-timage-or-just-tbitmap) информацию, понял что вроде бы как нужно создавать свой класс изображения, однако там все написано вскользь и конкретики никакой. Почитав на [официальном сайте](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/riff_container?csw=1), который поддерживает данный формат,  понял, что по своей сути Google WebP изображение является RIFF-контейнером.

Там же прочитал, что WebP может быть построен как DLL, которая экспортирует API libwebp.

Эти функции затем могут быть импортированы в C # и пример работы с функцией кодирования собственно, который приведен ниже.

```
[DllImport("libwebp.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int WebPEncodeBGRA(IntPtr rgba, int width, int height, int stride,
                                 float quality_factor, out IntPtr output);
[DllImport("libwebp.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern int WebPFree(IntPtr p);

void Encode() {
  Bitmap source = new Bitmap("input.png");
  BitmapData data = source.LockBits(
      new Rectangle(0, 0, source.Width, source.Height),
      ImageLockMode.ReadOnly,
      PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
  IntPtr webp_data;
  const int size = WebPEncodeBGRA(data.Scan0,
                                  source.Width, source.Height, data.Stride,
                                  80, out webp_data);
  // ...
  WebPFree(webp_data);
}
```

Как реализовать функции кодирования/декодирования изображений?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ничего сложного в этих функциях нет, за исключением того, что они сами выделяют память с помощью сишной функции `malloc()` или похожей, освобождать которую нужно `free()` из того же диспетчера C RTL.

`WebPDecodeRGBInto` использует готовый буфер, так что в одну сторону можно сработать без утечки.

P.S. Как @zed отметил, в библиотеке есть функция освобождения буферов WebPFree. Она описана [здесь](https://github.com/webmproject/libwebp/blob/master/src/webp/encode.h#L82), но в экземпляре DLL, скачанном по ссылке, она не экспортируется. Видимо, нужна версия DLL посвежее.

На тестовой картинке гора с лесом.

```
var
  src, dst: TBytes;
  data, pb: PByte;
  iy, wdt, hgt, datasize, stride: Integer;
  bmp: TBitmap;
begin
  src := TFile.ReadAllBytes('test.webp');
  if WebPGetInfo(@src[0], Length(src), @wdt, @hgt) > 0 then begin

    bmp := TBitmap.Create;
    bmp.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
    bmp.Width := wdt;
    bmp.Height := hgt;
{
    //использование  WebPDecodeRGB ведёт к утечке памяти
    data := WebPDecodeRGB(@src[0], Length(src), @wdt, @hgt);
    for iy := 0 to hgt - 1 do
      MoveMemory(bmp.ScanLine[iy], @data[iy * wdt * 3], wdt * 3);
 }
    SetLength(dst, wdt*hgt*3);
    pb :=WebPDecodeRGBInto(@src[0], Length(src), @dst[0],Length(dst), wdt*3);
    for iy := 0 to hgt - 1 do
      MoveMemory(bmp.ScanLine[iy], @dst[iy * wdt * 3], wdt * 3);

    Canvas.Draw(0, 0, bmp);

    //пакуем опять в webp
    //увы, data не освободить - утечка
    stride := NativeInt(bmp.ScanLine[1]) - NativeInt(bmp.ScanLine[0]);
    datasize := WebPEncodeRGB(bmp.ScanLine[0], wdt, hgt, stride, 80, data);
    SetLength(src, datasize);
    MoveMemory(src, data, datasize);
    TFile.WriteAllBytes('tnew.webp', src);

    bmp.Free;
  end;
```

Comment: Наверное и пример можно было написать с использованием `WebPDecodeRGBInto`? А то копи-пастеры от утечек памяти будут страдать.

Comment: @zed Да, сделаю обратный процесс и это.

Comment: Для освобождения памяти есть функция [WebPFree](https://github.com/webmproject/libwebp/blob/master/src/webp/encode.h#L82), её же можно использовать и в [декодере](https://github.com/webmproject/libwebp/blob/master/src/webp/decode.h#L94).

Comment: MBo, Огромное человеческое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

MBo, используя код (при чтении Webp), приведённый выше получилось так, что на выходе изображение получилось отличное от исходного.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Было решено уже в самом bitmap-е поменять каналы RGB (сделать так называемый swap) местами, тогда всё получается как нужно.

```
var
  src, dst: TBytes;
  iy, wdt, hgt, X, Y: Integer;
  bmp: TBitmap;
  R, G, B: Byte;
  C: TColor;
begin
  src := TFile.ReadAllBytes('test.webp');
  if WebPGetInfo(@src[0], Length(src), @wdt, @hgt) > 0 then
  begin
    bmp := TBitmap.Create;
    bmp.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
    bmp.Width := wdt;
    bmp.Height := hgt;
    SetLength(dst, wdt * hgt * 3);

    WebPDecodeRGBInto(@src[0], Length(src), @dst[0], Length(dst), wdt * 3);
    for iy := 0 to hgt - 1 do
      MoveMemory(bmp.ScanLine[iy], @dst[iy * wdt * 3], wdt * 3);
    begin
      for Y := 0 to bmp.Height - 1 do
      begin
        for X := 0 to bmp.Width - 1 do
        begin
          C := bmp.Canvas.Pixels[X, Y];
          R := GetRValue(C);
          G := GetGValue(C);
          B := GetBValue(C);
          bmp.Canvas.Pixels[X, Y] := RGB(B, G, R)
        end;
      end;
      Image1.Picture.Assign(bmp);
      bmp.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: А WebPDecode**BGR** не для этого ли случая предназначена?

Comment: MBo, извиняюсь, конечно да. В той функции как раз битмап создаётся в как нужно.И ещё, вопрос возник как обратную операцию производить. Вроде понял что часть кода идёт после  "//пакуем опять в webp", но как именно в Webp запихать обратно bmp так и не разобрался. Плюс там как-то могут применяться параметры сжатия самого BMP при кодировании его в WebP. Как их использовать?

Comment: Так я тот же битмап обратно запаковал. Размер webp будет не такой, как вначале -  из-за сжатия.

Comment: Т.е. моё предложенное решение вдруг перестало быть решением? ;)

Comment: MBo, не-не-не, браузер глюкнул, решение самое верное...